# What does usage mean in Amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I wanna have a personal website and instead of hosting, I rather go with Amazon cloud.

I'm confused about the usage though, if my website is not being browsed by anyone, is that considered in use or not?

Does Amazon only charge based on usage? or is there a flat option?

I'm gonna be the primary user of this website, I want to have my cv on it, maybe a blog, have a private wiki knowledge based, and stuff like that.

What plan/option do you think is best for me?

Comment: One good thing about ec2 is you are only charged for usage while your server is Started or Online. While the instance is Stopped you'll only pay for EBS volumes, basically your storage space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read the EC2 pricing documentation carefully and then ask specific questions about parts you do not understand:

> http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

For starters in your situation, you would pay the most attention to sections like:

- On-Demand Instances (probably t1.micro or m1.small to start)
- Data Transfer
- Elastic Block Store (you'll probably have an 8GB EBS volume as your root)

You pay for each hour that your instance (server) is running, whether anybody is making requests or not.  You pay for each byte of network data transferred in/out.

Some amount of limited use is covered in the free tier, but you should monitor your AWS account activity page carefully to catch if you did something that starts accruing unexpected charges.